# Javascript - how to define class factory as Extjs style?

Tags: javascript, oop, extjs

I am trying to create a `Extjs` style object-oriented UI library for my project, but didn't know how to declare the class structure.

I need to create instance of the UI object in following style:

```
var Corejs = {}; // the top object of my library,
// var Corejs = function() {}; // or maybe should put it this way,
window.$C = Corejs;
// here should define a `Panel` class, that belong to Corejs in some format,
var aPanel = $C.create('Corejs.Panel', {width: '200px', height:'100px'});
```

Can anyone help me to add the lines that define the `Panel` class, so  that I could create its instance in the way shows above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var Corejs = {
  classes: {}, // Class name to constructor map
  create: function(name, properties) {
    try  {
      var clazz = Corejs.classes[name];
      var instance = new clazz();

      for (var property in properties) {
        instance[property] = properties[property];
      }

      return instance;

    } catch (error) {
      // Handle this however you want
    }
  }
};
```

To make the above approach work, your Corejs components will just need to register themselves with the shared Corejs library like so:

```
var Panel = function() { /* ... */ };

Corejs.classes['Panel'] = Panel;
```

Note that the above approach would only work for classes that don't require parameters be passed to their constructors.

Comment: This helps, can you also suggest on where to put the `Panel` class, I don't want to put it as direct property of `window`, maybe put it as `Corejs`'s property, but since `Corejs` is just an object, and I want to develop components in individual js files, e.g. the definition of `Corejs` and `Panel` will be in different files, so can you suggest how to append `Panel` to `Corejs`?

Comment: Ah, right. I wasn't exactly clear on what types of things you'd be creating. Yeah, you could put it as a property of Corejs. I'll updated my example.